# How to Draw emoji on libgdx text?

Tags: libgdx

i got a string called "emoji", but in render does not show anything. I tried hex, decimal, char and paste the emoji as source, same result, nothing. On editor and logs I can see the emoji sucesfully... but not in running game texts.

font.draw(batch,emoji, 200, 200);

Any idea...?

Comment: The in-game font has a limited set of characters. It's up to you to create the font ahead of time using a tool like BMFont or Heiro. But I don't think either of these makes it easy to put emoji into the font. You might have use a more manual solution combined with something like Shoebox.

Comment: 255 characters, the basic set. Thanks!

Comment: I have loaded a font with emojis and libgdx only renders the english characters, not the emoji characters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635857/how-to-render-an-emoji-with-libgdx