# How to render an emoji with libgdx

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, libgdx, emoji

I have loaded a [font with emoji support](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font) and I am trying to render a string with emoji's with libgdx. However, it renders the text, but not the emojis.

### Code

#### Load Font

```java
FileHandle fontFile = Gdx.files.internal("path/to/file.ttf");
FreeTypeFontGenerator g = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(fontFile);
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter p = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
// Some config here with p
BitmapFont emojiFont= g.generateFont(p);
```

#### Render Font

```java
public static void renderFont(SpriteBatch sb, BitmapFont font, String msg, float x, float y, Color c) {
  font.setColor(c);
  font.draw(sb, msg, x, y);
}

String str = "emoji ❤ \uD83D\uDC49 test \uD83D\uDC49 \uD83D\uDC4D test \uD83D\uDE03"
renderFont(sb, emojiFont, str, x, y, new Color(-597249));
```

### Output

`emoji test test`

### Questions

1. Why is libgdx not rendering the emojis?
2. What do I need to change to render the emojis?

Answer (score 1):

FreeTypeFontGenerator creates a BitmapFont from your TTF file. Most likely your created font does not contain the emojis.

You don't show the interesting part of your code: the parameters you set. Add the emojis you want to use to the parameters:

```
p.characters = "characters you want to use";
```

Comment: There are over 2000 emojis. Do I need to include all of those in p.characters. Is there an easier solution (that I assume would be similar as for adding Chinese characters)?

Comment: @alexdriedger p.characters is the characters that FreeTypeGenerator has to include in generated bitmap font, you should add only the emojies and characters you need, to p.characters  in order to render them.